# Arduino Uno + servo motor (SG-90) + ultrasonic sensor(HC-S04) detects an obstacle

Tags: c++, arduino, servo, arduino-ultra-sonic

I'm a newbie to Arduino. The goal is to write a program that can stop a hypothetical conveyor belt (read a servo motor) if too many objects are stacked on a belt, that is detected by HC-S04 sensor. If the the distance exceeds the minimum threshold value (1000), then the motor can freely spin. If not, it should stop. With the code below, I get a servo motor to spin regardless of whether an object is in front of it or not. 
Tried taking out and changing the `delay`. It just was spinning faster or slower, but still ignored obstacle distance. Tried commenting  `sensorValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 255, 0, 4000);` but it didn't affect the result.

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Servo servo;
const int trigPin= 9;
const int echoPin= 10;
const int threshold = 1000;

void setup() {
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin,INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
servo.attach(8);

}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = digitalRead(echoPin);
  sensorValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 255, 0, 4000);
  if (sensorValue >= threshold) {
    digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
    delay(10);
   }

  else {
    digitalWrite(8,LOW);
   delay(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/UltrasonicSensor

Comment: https://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Servo

Answer (score 0):

Debug by outputting your `sensorValue` contents - this will allow you to check which branch is triggered.

(can't post as a comment because my rep is not high enough).

You can use the debugging values to check, configure and calibrate your sensor.